# detect patternts and digits in image with openCV and python

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to create a program that can input an image (I am doing it by imageGrab from PIL) and detect some known symbols in it, and their locations. The good thing is that I am pretty sure I don't need neural networks, because I know the exact shape and size of each symbol. the problem is that I have no idea how much of these will be, and what is the color in the background of each symbol. some of the symbols are numbers, I have an image of each digit 0-9, but there may be up to 3-digit numbers. I think I will be able to find a way to know which digits are part of the same number by their location, but lets talk about it later. right now, I have turned the image into grayscale and imshow it using opencv2.

do you have any idea how can I do it with opencv? some other library?
and I need it to be fast enough, hopefuly 10 frames per second.

this is my current code (modified [sentdex's "python plays GTA" code](https://pythonprogramming.net/game-frames-open-cv-python-plays-gta-v/), the most bottom of the page):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2

def screen_record(): 
    while(True):

        global printscreen

        image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(20,270,430,685))
        printscreen = np.array(image)
        grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        cv2.imshow('window', grayscale_image)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('w'):
            image.save("screen_shot.png")
            print("Saved current window as image")

screen_record()
```

EDIT: I managed to get to something with opencv's template match, only with the digit 2 (for now). I found a nice tutorial [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html). my problem is when there is not exactly 1 match of the template, means no number 2s, or more then 1. when there aren't any it looks like its choosing something random on the image, and when there's more then one, I have only 1 of them detected. is it ossible to apply it in a different way to match my needs?

Comment: Some sample images would be of great help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have a solution to my problem.
For all of those who reach this page in the future to get help, here are the steps to regognize templates in images:

create 2 images, the one you want to detect, and another one for your template.
then, upload the whoever you want using opencv, and copy this function:

```
def locate_symbol(x, template):
    w, h = filter_num2.shape[::-1]

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(x, template, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

    min_thresh = 0.45
    match_locations = np.where(res<=min_thresh)

    return w, h, match_locations
```

and use these lines to draw bounding boxes on the image:

```
w, h, locs = locate_symbol(grayscale_image, filter_num2)

for (x, y) in zip(locs[1], locs[0]):
    cv2.rectangle(printable_image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), [255, 0, 0], 2)
```

then you can draw everything with cv2.imshow()